# Nonblinking cursor in xmonad

Tags: gnome-terminal, xmonad, cursor

I'm trying to get a nonblinking cursor in `gnome-terminal`.

In gnome I used `gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_blink_mode -t string off` do accomplish this. How can i stop the cursor from blinking in xmonad?

Comment: Right-click and preferences? Xmonad doesn't control how your cursor blinks.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the `gconf2` package and using the same command you suggested worked for me.  I'm running `XMonad` on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink
```

Set it to default by invoking it in a script that is run with superuser privileges every time you boot your computer (that is, if you'd like to try it in a VT first, use `su -c` and then quote the command).

I have mine in `/etc/rc.local` - it works, although I suspect that file had another purpose originally.

If you use bash, you could do something like this (in `.bashrc`):

```
BLUEBOXNOBLINK="\033[?17;0;60c"
PS1="\[$BLUEBOXNOBLINK\] ...    # set it as a prefix
```